# Counter Box, Visible for all clients

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, counter

Hello I need a button for my website, that will start a countdown from 60 secounds to 0, then it should display some text (lets drink, cheers) and go back to start button.

All users must be able to see this countdown, so that when a user start the countdown other users can see this.

It should also display a counter, of howmany user have clicked the button, and joining in on the "button"

I have looked into this, but i need to do Ajax / javascript pulling.

Since my programming skill is still on copy/paste/edit level, I do not know howto get started, I can build the timer, but dont know howto do the pulling.

can anyone help me get started.

Regards 
 René

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first of all, you need a stateful backend, to store a usercount. So php+any db.

you mentioned socket.io, build on nodejs.

With nodejs this aint this difficult, because its a single threaded runtime, so you can share variable values to different clients.

your nodejs have to listen to 3 urls:

1. for passing the basing page ( can be done without nodejs, just url to html)
2. ajax url for passing clicks on a button from client to backend, returns current count
3. ajax url to pass the current seconds, returns current count and connected users.

everytime the 2. channels gets called, you need to check , if the countdown is alrdy running. if not: start it, else increase clicked counter.

like this:

```
//nodejs code
var currendSeconds=60;
var connectedClients = 0;
var threadid;

function clientClickedButton(req, res){ // 2. url
     if(currendSeconds==60 || ) {
          threadid = setInterval(function(){
                currendSeconds--;
                if(currentSeconds == 0){
                    clearInterval(threadid);
                }
          }, 1000);  //your counter
     }
     connectedClients++;
     res.send(currendSeconds);
}
```

your clientside have to listen to click event on the button, send a ajax req to 2.url and display the returned seconds ( from now on our dont need to request the seconds, just set up a count down clientside, without requesting the current seconds. )

Comment: Okay, Not sure i can run nodejs, since im am on hosted cpanel, no shell access.

Comment: So I might need to look into a pulling solution instead,  this will give me some delay though...

Comment: I ended op using Jquery combined with Ajax / php  / Mysql combination to solve my issue. Thanks for getting me started.
Regards
René